# How do I make Affectiva call my callback functions?

Tags: c#, wpf, callback, affdex-sdk

I recently installed the Affectiva SDK (http://www.affectiva.com/) and followed the tutorial on analyzing input from the camera (http://developer.affectiva.com/v3/android/analyze-camera/). Unfortunately, the project does not seem to be working. It is my understanding that the interface/callback functions from `FaceListener, ImageListener, ProcessStatusListener` need to be called when a face is detected etc (is this correct).

I am not getting any errors, but these functions are never called either (I've put Console.WriteLine statements in there, as well as placed breakpoints in Visual Studio). From time to time, a series of "Image Captured" statements are printed to the console, but I cannot yet reproduce how or why that happens. Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thank you in advance for any help.

---

Below is my code so far:

> App.xaml.cs

```
using Affdex;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Affectiva
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application, FaceListener, ImageListener, ProcessStatusListener
    {
        public static CameraDetector detector;
        int camId = 10;
        int camFPS = 60;

        public App(){
            detector = new CameraDetector();
            String classifierPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Affectiva\\Affdex SDK\\data";
            detector.setClassifierPath(classifierPath);

            detector.setCameraId(camId);
            detector.setCameraFPS(camFPS);

            detector.setFaceListener(this);
            detector.setImageListener(this);
            detector.setProcessStatusListener(this);

            detector.setDetectSmile(true);
            detector.setDetectJoy(true);

            detector.setDetectAllExpressions(true);
            detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true);
            detector.setDetectAllEmojis(true);
            detector.setDetectAllAppearances(true);
        }

        public void onFaceFound(float f, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Face Found!");
        }

        public void onFaceLost(float f, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Face Lost!");
        }

        public void onImageResults(Dictionary<int, Face> faces, Frame f){
            Console.WriteLine("OnImageResults - " + faces.Count);
            if(faces.Count > 0)
                Console.WriteLine(faces.First().Value.Appearance.Age);
        }

        public void onImageCapture(Frame f){
            Console.WriteLine("Image Captured " + f.getHeight());
        }

        public void onProcessingFinished()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing Finished");
        }

        public void onProcessingException(AffdexException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using WebEye.Controls.Wpf;

namespace Affectiva
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnStartButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cameraId = webCameraControl.GetVideoCaptureDevices().First();
            webCameraControl.StartCapture(cameraId);
            App.detector.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the wrong documentation.You can find the right documentation for Windows SDK [here](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_1/windows/). A quick look at the code snippet, you are setting `int camId = 10;` which means that the detector is looking for Camera with id 10 on the system. By default the inbuilt camera has an `id = 0`. We set the default CameraId to 0 and the rate at which we process the frames to 30.Here is the default constructor definition for [CameraDetector](http://developer.affectiva.com/pages/platforms/v3_1_1/windows/classdocs/Affdex/html/1d7a795f-92f8-e0e5-f48a-79d1d1941091.htm).

You can analyze the camera feed using this [example](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_1/windows/analyze-camera/). We also have some ready to go application available on github mainly [Affdex-Me](https://github.com/Affectiva/affdexme-win) and [csharp-sample-apps](https://github.com/Affectiva/csharp-sample-apps).

Comment: Whoops, I linked the wrong documentation. I did in fact use [this](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_1/windows/analyze-camera/) documentation. The id thing seems like a very silly mistake, I changed it to 0 now, but it still does not work, unfortunately.

I will now take a look at your github examples, and see if I can learn from them. Thank you for your response!